# pusher authentication socket id undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift, pusher

I'm trying to create a private channel to allow users to send data to my node.js server. The request is failing, and returning a pusher:subscription_error with an error code of 500.

My node.js (server side) log cannot pull the socket_id from the incoming request to '/pusher/auth'

```
app.post( '/pusher/auth', function( req, res ) {
  var socketId = req.body.socket_id;//<--DEBUG: TypeError: Cannot read property 'socket_id' of undefined

  var channel = req.body.channel_name;
  var presenceData = {
    user_id: 'unique_user_id',
    user_info: {
      name: 'Mr Pusher',
      twitter_id: '@pusher'
    }
  };
  var auth = pusher.auth( socketId, channel, presenceData );
  res.send( auth );
} );
```

Here is the client side which sends the request:

```
   // Create new Pusher instance and connect
        var key = "<%= appKey %>"  
        var id = "<%= appKey %>"  
        var secret = "<%= appSecret %>"  
        var pusher = new Pusher( "<%= appKey %>" );

// Subscribe to the channel that the event will be published on
var channel = pusher.subscribe( 'private-channel' );
    channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded',function(){
            alert("subscription succeeded")
            var triggered = channel.trigger("client-event",{})
            alert("triggered "+triggered)
    })
    channel.bind('pusher:subscription_error',function(status){
            alert("subscription error "+status)//<-- This error gets returned
    })
// Bind to the event on the channel and handle the event when triggered
channel.bind( 'client-event', function( data ) {
  // For now, alert the message.
  alert( data.message );
} );
```

Should this be automatically handled by the pusher API, or do I need to explicitly send it?
How can I send the socket_id to the server? 
How can I even access the socket_id variable on the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to set up the `bodyParser` which will parse the request body and make `request.body` available.

See the Pusher docs: http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#implementing_private_endpoints/lang=node

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was missing the line "app.use( express.bodyParser() );" and I was looking in all the wrong places for the fix.